# How to set unchecked checkbox 1 When checkbox 2 was checked and set unchecked checkbox 2 When checkbox 1 was checked using script?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

How to  set unchecked checkbox 1 When checkbox 2 was checked and set unchecked checkbox 2 When checkbox 1 was checked

( Make checkbox working like radio button. )

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox1"/> checkbox 1 
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" value="checkbox2"/> checkbox2

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('checkbox1').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('checkbox2').Unchecked = this.checked;

};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('checkbox2').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('checkbox1').Unchecked = this.checked;

};
</script>
```

Comment: "Make checkbox working like radio button". Users have certain interface expectations and changing them is usually a bad idea. Also, why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: If a user can only use on selection, then radio buttons would be more appropriate.

Comment: I second what j08691 says. Users expect checkboxes to allow them to select multiple items, and radio buttons to only allow for one item to be selected. Changing that around goes against pretty well established UX methodologies. Is there a reason you have to use a checkbox and can't use radio buttons/a radio button list?

Comment: i not use radio button because radio button can not clear all select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .checked and not unchecked and set its property to false

```
document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked = false;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wFGdL/1/)

Comment: but i can not uncheked all ?

Comment: Well if you have more add them to your list and put their checked = false like my exemple is already doing

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery -

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change',function(){
   if(this.checked)
     $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
});
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/3g67r/

Comment: can i use getElementById for target ?

not all input:checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use the right input type for the job.

Check boxes allow multiple selections while radio buttons do not.  Users should expect them to work like that and would get confused if check boxes worked like radio buttons (I know I would get confused.)

Use the right input and forget about overriding functionality with javascript.  (Don't forget, they could have javascript turned off which would potentially cause you problems that using the right input would prevent)